# LINQ: How to Transpose 1D Array into 2D Array By Row

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

Is there a way in Linq to take each element in my string[] and assign each element to a square Multi-Dimensional(2D) array by its row. Meaning, 2D[0,i], where i increments by 1 assigning 1D[i] there. Note, 1D array is guaranteed to be same length as width of 2D array. Also, my 2D array accessor is limited to only a class indexer, so my class indexer looks like this, CLASS[r,c].

Here is how I'm creating my 1D array: `lineRead.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

In sudo code, this is what I want to achieve.

`lineRead.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(e => CLASS[r,c] = e);`

I'm terrible with Linq and I feel like there should be a way to do this, obviously I don't know what I'm doing with Linq here... Lol
Any ideas, any help? Thanks

Comment: What is `r` in your `CLASS` indexer? Is it always `0`?

Comment: This gist might helps: https://gist.github.com/kekyo/2e0c456f506ec31431f33741608d5230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `r` is constant (`0`, since you don't mention in your post), here is one way of doing it:

```
string lineRead = "apple mango orange grape";
int i = 0;
lineRead.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.ToList()
.ForEach(item => { CLASS[0, i++] = item; });
```

Sample Output:

> CLASS[0,0] = "apple"
>
> CLASS[0,1] = "mango"
>
> CLASS[0,2] = "orange"
>
> CLASS[0,3] = "grape"

Although quite frankly, a good old `for` loop would do just as well:

```
string lineRead = "apple mango orange grape";
var values = lineRead.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    CLASS[0,i] = values[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you this does help a ton. I ended up going with a loop, but I might refactor into a Linq statement, because your solution is so elegant. What do you think about performance of the two?

Comment: @MatthewJett: I am glad I was able to help. Performance is probably around the same for both. I personally prefer more readable code. Good luck!